# Ratio of length to baseplate bolt pattern to assume that a joint is pinned

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, beam

I have a truss tower that is attached to a hoist arm by a baseplate. The truss tower is 80ft long and the bolt pattern of the baseplate is a 1ftx1ft square. Is it valid to assume that the joint between the truss and the hoist arm is a pinned joint?

Comment: Could you post a diagram of the structure and the supports?